# Cloudbees support for Worker thread

Tags: queue, cloudbees, worker

Is there any support on Cloudbees for worker processes/threads, like Worker Dynos on Heroku or Queues on GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you're looking for som asynchronous task executor, aren't you ?
inside your application you could implement this as a ServiceExecutor thread pool. Compared to GAE, RUN@Cloud don't have Thread restrictions. To distribute tasks on multiple nodes you will need a message queue service that we don't provide. You can have a look at [amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) or [rabbit MQ SaaS CloudAMQP](http://www.cloudamqp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Each app on CloudBees is alike - there is no need to designate one as a worker dyno type thing - people often use that pattern (they have an app that is effectively a worker - but it is just an app - any app can do that work).

You can run things like quartz scheduler as well.